# dd command to adjust to file system

Tags: linux, shell, command

I have a problem using `dd` command, assume that I am writing 20MB file to 100MB partition. After the write I am not able to access the rest of 80MB.

```
dd if=temp_file of=/dev/sdb1
```

Is there a way I can specify `dd` to adjust to the file system that I am writing into?

All I am interested is know if there is a way to use the 80MB space without disturbing the initial 20MB.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `dd` command the way you do, you *overwrite* the file-system data, including the important meta-data about the file-system. If the `temp_file` contains a file-system for a 20MB partition then that's what you will get.

If you want a 100MB partition, you need to create a 100MB disk-image to write to the disk.